# Why is gradle building never finished on Android Studio 1.5?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have installed the Android Studio latest version 1.5. But I have never built even the hello world project, because the gradle, building for the project, is running forever.

These are the AS logs:

```
2016-03-08 15:14:24,355 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2016-03-08 15:14:24,867 [    512]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-141.2178183, 19 Aug 2015 00:00) 
2016-03-08 15:14:24,867 [    512]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 7 (6.1, x86) 
2016-03-08 15:14:24,867 [    512]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_73-b02 (Oracle Corporation) 
2016-03-08 15:14:24,867 [    512]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.73-b02 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM) 
2016-03-08 15:14:24,908 [    553]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms256m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=150m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.3 -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Djb.vmOptions=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\boot.jar -Didea.jre.check=false 
2016-03-08 15:14:25,511 [   1156]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (32-bit) in 603 ms 
2016-03-08 15:14:25,546 [   1191]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2016-03-08 15:14:25,574 [   1219]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
2016-03-08 15:14:33,199 [   8844]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 28 plugins initialized in 1591 ms 
2016-03-08 15:14:33,203 [   8848]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android NDK Support (1.0), Android Support (10.1.3.2), CVS Integration (11), Copyright (8.1), Coverage, EditorConfig (1.0), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, Google Cloud Testing (1.0), Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Login (1.0), Google Services (0.1), Gradle, Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java, IDEA CORE, IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (0.1), JavaFX (1.0), Maven Integration, Properties Support, SDK Updater (1.0), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), hg4idea (10.0) 
2016-03-08 15:14:38,075 [  13720]   INFO - ellij.concurrency.JobScheduler - 50 ms execution limit failed for: com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$1@6d52b; elapsed time was 55ms 
2016-03-08 15:14:38,150 [  13795]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=739246080 
2016-03-08 15:14:38,412 [  14057]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\fsnotifier.exe 
2016-03-08 15:14:38,490 [  14135]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2016-03-08 15:14:41,844 [  17489]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [] 
2016-03-08 15:14:44,532 [  20177]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63343 
2016-03-08 15:14:51,798 [  27443]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2016-03-08 15:14:52,545 [  28190]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 21 project components initialized in 4439 ms 
2016-03-08 15:14:52,545 [  28190]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2016-03-08 15:15:03,549 [  39194]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 88 application components initialized in 30087 ms 
2016-03-08 15:15:04,818 [  40463]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 44843 ms 
2016-03-08 15:15:15,861 [  51506]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2016-03-08 15:15:18,193 [  53838]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 142 project components initialized in 6884 ms 
2016-03-08 15:15:19,046 [  54691]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 2 module(s) loaded in 853 ms 
2016-03-08 15:15:30,622 [  66267]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 8454 ms 
2016-03-08 15:15:31,511 [  67156]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-03-08 15:15:31,613 [  67258]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-03-08 15:15:31,721 [  67366]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-03-08 15:15:31,806 [  67451]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-03-08 15:15:38,983 [  74628]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'Hello'. 
2016-03-08 15:15:42,082 [  77727]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40 
2016-03-08 15:15:42,170 [  77815]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40 
2016-03-08 15:15:42,798 [  78443]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository' 
2016-03-08 15:15:44,554 [  80199]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo53.gradle, --init-script, C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit31.gradle] 
2016-03-08 15:16:03,871 [  99516]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - D:\Project\Hello\.idea\misc.xml case-sensitivity: false 
2016-03-08 15:16:09,525 [ 105170]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
2016-03-08 15:16:10,723 [ 106368]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 4 
2016-03-08 15:16:11,201 [ 106846]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestCompatibleScreens 
2016-03-08 15:16:11,201 [ 106846]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestSupportsInput 
2016-03-08 15:16:17,403 [ 113048]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 66279 ms 
2016-03-08 15:16:19,021 [ 114666]   INFO - nject.config.XPathSupportProxy - XPath Support is not available 
2016-03-08 15:19:48,535 [ 324180]   INFO - on.console.RunIdeConsoleAction - Loading javax.script.* engines... 
2016-03-08 15:19:49,052 [ 324697]   INFO - on.console.RunIdeConsoleAction - org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineFactory: *.groovy: Groovy/2.3.9 (Groovy Scripting Engine/2.0) 
2016-03-08 15:20:29,379 [ 365024]   WARN - options.ex.ConfigurableWrapper - XML does not provide id for class com.android.tools.idea.run.CloudTestingConfigurable 
2016-03-08 15:20:30,007 [ 365652]   WARN - ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - Can't find parent for project.propCompiler (Compiler) 
2016-03-08 15:25:18,774 [ 654419]   WARN - options.ex.ConfigurableWrapper - XML does not provide id for class com.android.tools.idea.run.CloudTestingConfigurable 
2016-03-08 15:25:18,782 [ 654427]   WARN - ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - Can't find parent for project.propCompiler (Compiler) 
2016-03-08 15:28:49,224 [ 864869]   INFO - tools.idea.ddms.adb.AdbService - Initializing adb using: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe, client support = true 
2016-03-08 15:28:54,211 [ 869856]   INFO - tools.idea.ddms.adb.AdbService - Successfully connected to adb 
2016-03-08 15:28:54,213 [ 869858]   INFO - nitor.AndroidToolWindowFactory - Successfully obtained debug bridge 
2016-03-08 15:29:04,093 [ 879738]   INFO - android.run.AndroidDebugRunner - device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device. 
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:855)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:458)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:388)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:357)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:568)
    at org.jetbrains.android.util.AndroidUtils.executeCommandOnDevice(AndroidUtils.java:396)
    at org.jetbrains.android.logcat.AndroidLogcatUtil.startLogging(AndroidLogcatUtil.java:67)
    at org.jetbrains.android.logcat.AndroidLogcatUtil.access$100(AndroidLogcatUtil.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.android.logcat.AndroidLogcatUtil$4.run(AndroidLogcatUtil.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
2016-03-08 15:29:58,949 [ 934594]   INFO - openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl - Cache hits:4096, total requests:4317,null
```

Comment: even i have the same problem....in the beginning..what you need to do is,remove all your plugin's, like adb commander..and try again.

Comment: hello, Narendra. I have just done according to your mention, but still not working.

Comment: then, uninstall AS and re install it again, remove your all stuff in c drive which are belongs to AS, ex: gradle,android studio folders. Again start everything newly..hope will this help out you!